# Null Pointer Exception with an array of bitsets

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bitset

could someone explain to me why the following results in a Null pointer Exception? And how to set a value for bitarray[0]?

```
      BitSet[] bitarray;
      bitarray= new BitSet[10];
      bitarray[0].set(1);
```

Also, why something like this work and not result in a pointer exception?

```
     BitSet[] bitarray = new BitSet[10];
     BitSet bits = new BitSet(32);
     bits.set(1);
     bitarray[0] = bits;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find nice help on [Arrays Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

[image: Arrays]

In case of above example if you just declare array of `10 BitSet` because defualt value of `BitSet` is `null` so it contains all `null` references

```
BitSet[] bitarray = new BitSet[10];
```

So initialize the reference you need to do

```
bitarray[index] =  new BitSet(SomeValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize `bitarray` with

```
bitarray = new BitSet[10];
```

it is an array of 10 references, *all of which are `null`*. You need to initialize each reference before you can use it. In the second case, you are assigning `bits` to be the value of `bitarray[0]`. In the first case, you have not assigned anything to `bitarray[0]` before you call `set()`.

Answer (score 1):

`bitarray= new BitSet[10];` sets 10 indexes with value `null`.

First case

`bitarray[0]` is `null`. You didn't assign value. That is why `NPE`

Second case::

You are setting values to `Bitset` and then assigning it to `index 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized **bitarray** but must also initialize each item separately afterwards; otherwise what you have is an array of 10 null references.

Answer (score 0):

just because you have an array with space for ten things, doesn't mean that the array is **populated**.  In the working example, you are setting a value....